# Backing up and Migrating MongoDB Scehma on Docker

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, mongoose, database-migration

So for a project, we have setup a docker running MongoDB. Now I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to backup, and migrate the database.

I've done my research on some of the things but still have some questions that I'd like to some guidance on.

For now, I've managed to backup and restore the MongoDB database using `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands which I can run inside the mounted docker container.

I am now stuck on migration of the schema. We are using an `Express` backend and also `Mongoose` to write our models. If I am not wrong, there's no need to migrate a schema if I introduce a new attribute in a model, as long as it has a default value? Is that correct? What if there's no default value and it's a `required` field?

And is a schema migration *only* necessary if we change an existing attribute in a document?

Are there any specific articles that can help me out in this case?

Thanks